# Python 3 - UnboundLocalError problems

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
points1=0
points2=0
bank1=0
bank2=0
def gameloop():
    cont = "Keep going"
    while cont=="Keep going":
        roll1=random.randint(1,6)
        roll2=random.randint(1,6)
        if roll1+roll2==2:
            bank1=0
            points1=0
            print("Unlucky! You've lost your banked and running total! Now it's the next player's turn.")
        else:
            points1=points1+roll1+roll2 
#This is the first place I keep getting the problem.
```

So, I tried to shorten my code as much as possible so that it included all the necessary parts. This is as far as I think I can format it to make sense. Also, I can't remove the "def gameloop():" because I need it later. The problem here is, I keep getting UnboundLocalError and I've tried looking into it but I don't know exactly how to apply the solutions. Any help would be greatly appreciated - so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify `points1` and other variables within `gameloop`, but they are defined outside the scope of the `gameloop` function. Include them as arguments and then return their new values.

```
points1=0
points2=0
bank1=0
bank2=0
def gameloop(p1, p2, b1, b2):
    cont = "Keep going"
    while cont=="Keep going":
        roll1=random.randint(1,6)
        roll2=random.randint(1,6)
        if roll1+roll2==2:
            b1=0
            p1=0
            print("Unlucky! You've lost your banked and running total! Now it's the next player's turn.")
        else:
            p1=p1+roll1+roll2
    return p1, p2, b1, b2
```

And then when you call this function, it will give you those new values that it calculated rather than trying to act on variables not in its scope.

```
points1, points2, bank1, bank2 = gameloop(points1, points2, bank1, bank2)
```

Comment: So if I call back gameloop() using this the variables shouldn't reset? I'll try it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you variables

```
points1=0
points2=0
bank1=0
bank2=0
```

are outside the scope of your function `gameloop()`, so they aren't recognized inside the function.

You need to either pass them as parameters to the function like this: `gameloop(points1, points2, bank1, bank2)` 
or initialize them in the beginning of your function like this:

```
def gameloop():
    points1=0
    points2=0
    bank1=0
    bank2=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `global` keyword to make your in-function variables edit global variables. So that would be:

```
import random
points1=0
points2=0
bank1=0
bank2=0
def gameloop():
    global bank1
    global points1
    cont = "Keep going"
    while cont=="Keep going":
        roll1=random.randint(1,6)
        roll2=random.randint(1,6)
        if roll1+roll2==2:
            bank1=0
            points1=0
            print("Unlucky! You've lost your banked and running total! Now it's the next player's turn.")
        else:
            points1=points1+roll1+roll2
```